# 'incr' command giving error "Attempted to increment field that isn't 64 bits wide" in HBase shell

Tags: hbase

I want to set increment for a cell value so I ran 'incr' command on an HBase table. But getting following error :

**ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Attempted to increment field that isn't 64 bits wide**

Following are the commands which I ran:

```
hbase(main):022:0> create 'test1', {NAME => 'foo', VERSIONS => 1}
0 row(s) in 1.0440 seconds

hbase(main):023:0> put 'test1', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1
0 row(s) in 0.0120 seconds

hbase(main):024:0> scan 'test1'
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL
 spam                                       column=foo:bar, timestamp=1372922338444, value=1
1 row(s) in 0.0140 seconds

hbase(main):025:0> incr 'test1', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Attempted to increment field that isn't 64 bits wide

Here is some help for this command:
Increments a cell 'value' at specified table/row/column coordinates.
To increment a cell value in table 't1' at row 'r1' under column
'c1' by 1 (can be omitted) or 10 do:

  hbase> incr 't1', 'r1', 'c1'
  hbase> incr 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 1
  hbase> incr 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 10


hbase(main):026:0>
```

Any idea, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Mistake is in counter initialization. You don't need to initialize counter. It will be initialized when column is first time incremented with 8-bytes long *1* value, when in your case it was initialized with 4-bytes integer *1*. Correct usage is:

```
hbase(main):012:0> create 'test', {NAME => 'foo', VERSIONS => 1}
0 row(s) in 0.1470 seconds

=> Hbase::Table - test
hbase(main):013:0> incr 'test', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1
COUNTER VALUE = 1
0 row(s) in 0.0080 seconds

hbase(main):014:0> incr 'test', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1
COUNTER VALUE = 2
0 row(s) in 0.0060 seconds

hbase(main):015:0> incr 'test', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1
COUNTER VALUE = 3
0 row(s) in 0.0040 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use increment from the begining
if you want to initialize to a value other than zero increment with that number

so in you case you should

```
incr 'test1', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1
incr 'test1', 'spam', 'foo:bar', 1
```

to get a counter value of 2

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem
in my case the value in the specified increment location is an integer.
i changed the value to long

```
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("columnar"),Bytes.toBytes("column11111"), Bytes.toBytes(1l));
```

and performed increment operation it worked.

```
incr 'blah-blah','row111','columnar:column11111',11
```